# how to Remove the characters in between a string using index in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the few characters in a string using index.
for example:
   My input is: "5,4,3,2,1"
I want to remove the 1th to 2nd index position characters(here , to 4).
   The Output should be 5,3,2,1.
Is there any predefined function in jquery or javascript to done this?

Comment: Try `str = str.substr(0, 1) + str.substr(3)`

Comment: How about using `slice`?

Comment: @SandeepNayak It's saved in a string, not in an array, so you can't use `slice`

Comment: @nameless It can be used on string as well. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: thank you for try to help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use substring function like this:

```
var mystring = "5,4,3,2,1";
alert( mystring.substr(0, 1) + mystring.substr(3));
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/63g51tbd/)**

Answer (score 1):

I would juse use javascripts `split` function for that.

So if you have

```
 var string = "5,4,3,2,1";
```

than you just need to do

```
var splitted = string.split(",");
```

whereas the character in the brackets is the one you want to split on. After you did that, you can just make a new string, and build it with the array elements.

So you do something like

```
var string2 = splitted[0] + "," + splitted[2] + "," + splitted[3] + "," splitted[4];
```

Comment: Thank you for try to help me.